# Are all graphs induces on Voronoi of ALL metrics are planar?

Tags: geometry, voronoi-diagram

Graph induced by Voronoi on Euclidean distance is planar (Delaunay triangulation). Is it true for other distance metrics : L_p where $1\leq p \leq \inf$? It seems to be true by definition of Voronoi, but I am not sure...

Comment: What does "planar" mean in the case of, say, the discrete metric?